# Fb Like in Ember App

Tags: facebook, ember.js, facebook-like

In my ember app I am trying to add fb like button. I have this flow.

index -> select Image -> pay -> thank you page

In my thank you page I am trying this fb like code

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Postify.Postcards" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

The problem is when I am coming the above mentioned flow it doesn't show a like button. But when I am on thank you page and the refresh then it shows the fb like button.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook parses the page on page load for instances of Facebook items, since you're dynamically adding it after page load it doesn't catch it.  You'll just need to re-parse the page, or re-parse that item when you hit a template where that applies.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Something like this would be the way to solve it.

```
App.ThankYouView = Ember.View.extend({
  setupFbLike: function(){
     FB.XFBML.parse();
  }.on('didInsertElement')
})
```